# Looping columns of data frame and plotting separately in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Below is my code Snippet. I would like to plot each column at a time against time in a line plot. Each column in different plots
But the plot seems to keep accumulating the older values in the bottom.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()


import re
def makeLinePlot(df):
    file_name="File Name not passed to this method"
    print("Ploting")
    df2=df
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(30,8))
    i=0
    numRos = df.columns.size
    for colName in df.columns:
        i=i+1
        print(file_name,colName)
        df2[colName]=df2[colName].astype(float)
        print(colName,df2[colName].shape)
        g=sns.lineplot(x=df2.index, y=df2[colName], ax=ax)
        colNameR = re.sub('\W+','', colName )
        g.get_figure().savefig(colNameR+".png")


range = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', freq='1min')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range)

# Average speed in miles per hour
df['speed'] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=60, size=len(df.index))
# Distance in miles (speed * 0.5 hours)
df['distance'] = df['speed'] * 0.25 
# Cumulative distance travelled
df['cumulative_distance'] = df.distance.cumsum()
makeLinePlot(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, due to `ax=ax` both lineplots are plotted to the same axes. So you need to create two figures, and hence two axes and then you can plot each line to its own `ax`.

Comment: How to fix it..

Comment: You need `fig,ax = ...` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code and now it seems I have got what you want. Use the following code.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()


import re
def makeLinePlot(df):
    df2=df
    i=0

    numRos = df.columns.size

    fig,ax =plt.subplots( nrows=1, ncols=numRos,figsize=(30,8))

    for index, colName in enumerate(df.columns):
        i=i+1
        df2[colName]=df2[colName].astype(float)
        print(colName,df2[colName].shape)
        g=sns.lineplot(x=df2.index, y=df2[colName], ax=ax[index])
        colNameR = re.sub('\W+','', colName )
        g.get_figure().savefig(colNameR+".png")


range = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', freq='1min')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range)

# Average speed in miles per hour
df['speed'] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=60, size=len(df.index))
# Distance in miles (speed * 0.5 hours)
df['distance'] = df['speed'] * 0.25 
# Cumulative distance travelled
df['cumulative_distance'] = df.distance.cumsum()
makeLinePlot(df)
```

I have got this.
[image]